# python: backtrace.hook does not work with backtrace.print_exc()

Tags: python, exception, traceback, backtrace

I can't figure out how to color a backtrace I print myself.

This colors my backtrace:

```
#!/bin/python3
import backtrace
backtrace.hook()
raise Exception('here')
```

But if I catch the exception and print it... then no color:

```
#!/bin/python3
import backtrace
backtrace.hook()
import traceback
try:
    raise Exception('here')
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I know these are 2 different packages, but they should be able to work together.

How do I catch and print exceptions (and a stack trace) in color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backtrace` internally uses [`sys.excepthook` do the trick](https://github.com/nir0s/backtrace/blob/a1f75c956f669a6175088693802d5392e6bd7e51/backtrace.py#L186). When [an **exception is raised and uncaught**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook), the interpreter calls `sys.excepthook` with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback object. In your first case, when you call `backtrace.hook()`, the `backtrace` library essentially set the `sys.excepthook` to a [custom function](https://github.com/nir0s/backtrace/blob/a1f75c956f669a6175088693802d5392e6bd7e51/backtrace.py#L158) which can do all sorts of magic with the exception instance(coloring etc....)

```
>>> def custom_hook(*args):
...     print(args)
...
>>>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.excepthook = custom_hook
>>>
>>> 1 / 0 # No exception raised, instead it calls `custom_hook`
(<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), <traceback object at 0x000001FA502B98C0>)
```

The `excepthook` **does not call if the exception is raised and caught(using `except`)**.

```
>>> def custom_hook(*args):
...     print(args)
...
>>>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.excepthook = custom_hook
>>>
>>> try:
...     1 / 0 
... except: # Since the exception is caught here, it won't call `custom_hook`
...     pass
...
```

The exact scenario happened in your case. You have to re-raise the exception once it's caught to get the excepted behavior.

Comment: Ok, but... when I catch an exception, how do I print a colored stack trace?

Comment: `traceback.print_exc()` display just printable representation of the exception traceback. You have to do it manually or re-raise the exception!

Comment: Thank you.  This works:  except Exception as e:
    sys.excepthook(e.__class__, e, e.__traceback__)